# mysql join query is not working properly

Tags: php, mysql

### Question:

I want to create invoice using so_dtl table. I have write query for it and its working fine in normal senario. But in some condition its give wrong result.

### My requirement:

- User can create invoice using appropreate so_num
- Invoice items automatically fill up from so_dtl tables using refernce of so_num
- User can edit quantity as per requirement

### Invoice Condition:

- If once invoice generated for specific so_num then when another invoice generated for same so_num it should generated deducted quantity
- I gave multiple SO support for invoice
- When two so_num selsected for creating invoice and one of the so_num is already used in invoice, then the quantity of already used so_num should be deducted from corresponding so_num of so_dtl and  another so_num selected for invoice should generated using orinal quantity from so_dtl

### Tables:

1. inv_master

   id    so_num     invoice_type

   ```
   1       1       PROFORMA INVOICE
   2       1       SAMPLE INVOICE
   ```
2. inv_details

   id     inv_id    so_num      finish_good      item_desc              qty     unit_price

   ```
   1       1         1            565        WRE Electronics Card      20          5 
   2       1         1            564        WRE ELECTRONICS           10          5
   3       2         1            565        WRE Electronics Card      10          5 
   4       2         1            564        WRE ELECTRONICS           5           5
   ```
3. so_dtl

   id    so_num      finish_good      item_desc               qty     unit_price

   ```
   1      1            565        WRE Electronics Card       20          5      
   2      1            564        WRE ELECTRONICS            10          5
   3      2            444        TEST-PRODUCT               10          4
   4      3            54         FPGA Based PM              5           6
   5      4            52         FPGA Based PWM             5           6
   6      5            560        Test Desc                  5           5
   ```

### I have tried query as below:

```
select 
    sid.so_num, 
    sid.finish_good as fgood_id, 
    sid.item_desc as description, 
    sid.qty, 
    sid.unit_price, 
    sid.qty - (select sum(qty) from inv_details where finish_good=sid.finish_good and so_num=sid.so_num) as final_qty 
from 
    so_dtl sid 
inner join inv_master as i  
on i.so_num=sid.sales_id 
where sid.so_num IN(1,4) and 
      i.invoice_type!='PROFORMA INVOICE';
```

### table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `so_dtl`(
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `so_num` int(4) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Store id of sales order',
  `finish_good` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `item_desc` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `qty` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `unit_price` decimal(13,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `total` decimal(13,2) NOT NULL,
  `createdon` datetime NOT NULL,
  `createdby` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `modifiedon` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modifiedby` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `deleted` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ;



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `inv_master` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `inv_no` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `invoice_type` varchar(35) NOT NULL);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `inv_details` (
  `inv_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `invoice_id` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `so_num` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `item_dsc` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `qty` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `unit_price` decimal(13,2) NOT NULL,
  `total` decimal(13,2) NOT NULL,
  `createdon` datetime NOT NULL,
  `createdby` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `finish_good` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `fgood_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `modifiedon` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modifiedby` int(3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`inv_item_id`)
);
```

Comment: What outcome do you get and what is expected output?

Comment: @LIUFA i want total quantity after subtraction without repetition of item. if item already insert more than one time.

Comment: can u give your table structure

Comment: see table structure i have already defined

Comment: type `show create table table_name`

Comment: @black i have updated question for table structure